# How should I implement a page in which the browser's back button will not ask about previously sent data?

Tags: php, forms

It's a bit hard to word this but I have found that some websites implement forms in which data can be passed to the next page and when the back button is clicked, the browser does not warn about previously sent data.

Comment: It's a pattern called PRG. You can have a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: That's just what I am looking for. Thanks. Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pattern called PRG. You can have a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to put them in session data or cookies... if you want it to go back and forth... you might check if variables are filled and then pop up on leaving the page, with custom message.

at least if I understand what you're asking.